# cat: /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, dhcp

I searched on how to print dhcp details on Ubuntu , I found few information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413624/how-can-i-find-my-dhcp-server). However it always displays "/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases: No such file or directory". How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What **version** of Ubuntu are you using? Networking has evolved a lot recently - see for example [Find DHCP Lease & DNS Info In 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039056/find-dhcp-lease-dns-info-in-18-04-lts)

Comment: @steeldriver Yes it's 18.04